# How load() is supposed to be used

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to understand how SvelteKit renders my web app in different scenarios, and I'm a bit puzzled by `load()`.

I created a page with a load function which calls an external API and uses the response as prop for the component. In `.svelte-kit/output/prerendered/pages/mypage.html` I can see that it has fetched the data during the build step, and prerendered my html using the response.

When I then navigate to that page in my web app, the network tab tells me that it calls the external API before rendering it. So, what was the point of prerendering then?

The SvelteKit docs says:

> A component that defines a page or a layout can export a load function that runs before the component is created. This function runs both during server-side rendering and in the client, and allows you to fetch and manipulate data before the page is rendered, thus preventing loading spinners.

I don't understand this. How can I prevent the loading spinner if its calling the API every time I navigate to the page? When is it supposed to use the prerendered html?

The whole concept of rendering both in the client and server doesn't make sense to me. The way I see it, I would want to prerender on the server if the data is static, but if it changes then I would want to call the API every time I go to the page (maybe with caching). But why would I want to do both??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But why would I want to do both?

Because server-side rendering tends to be faster on first load.

When the user directly visits the site, the server-side rendered version displays content more quickly under certain conditions, e.g. on a slow network or underpowered hardware if rendering the page is more complex.

A fully pre-rendered version is even faster, because not even the server has to perform any rendering or wait for requests.

On first load when accessing the pre-rendered route directly, you will get the pre-rendered page with the data that was requested during build time. But `load` is designed to run on both client and server, so it will run regardless of whether the page was pre-rendered or not.

This means that you can quickly get stale data when loading the page directly and slower but fresh data when navigating to it on the client.

I think what you would want to use for a truly static page is not a *page* `load` but a *server* `load` function (in `+page.server.ts/js`) or a [`GET` endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints), which will only ever run on the server and thus for pre-rendered pages it will only be run once during build.

Comment: But the page with the load function calls the external API the first time I navigate to it, so the prerendered version is not being used...?

And as you said, components are loaded as needed, and this load function is called before this specific component is rendered ... which will call the external API! It still doesn't make sense...

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate"? Are you accessing the URL of the given page directly or does client-side routing happen before that?

Comment: It's an SPA, so I mean client side routing. I'm navigating to the home page first, and then clicking on a link which routes me (client side) to the component with the load function

Comment: As I said, the pre-rendered version will only ever be used on first load of the page, unless the application is deployed as a collection of completely static files without routing. If there is any navigation beforehand, by default the pre-rendered file will *not* be used.

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully be more precise and offer a solution if you just want to prevent those additional API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! My page depends on getting fresh data, so I suppose it doesn't make sense to prerender it then? I understand that if the data is static, then yeah it makes sense to prerender it to reduce load time. But it still doesn't make sense to me to do both. If I need fresh data from the API, then why would I want to fetch and cache the response during build time? Sorry if I'm slow and just not "getting it".

Comment: You probably wouldn't. Doing that only makes sense if the load speed is more important than getting stale data. I doubt that there are many scenarios where people would opt for that. Server-side rendering usually makes sense, but pre-rendering has fewer, very specific use cases (e.g. blog articles or documentation, anything more document than application).

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is still relevant, but I had the same problem. As someone already mentioned `load` function is made to run on both server and client, **if you use +page.ts**, but, if you're using prerendering (SSG in Next.js terms), you can write your data fetching logic inside a `load` function in `+page.server.ts`. This file can have the same structure as your `+page.ts`, but will run **only** on the server: meaning if you use SSR, it will run on each request, but the server will do the heavy lifting and if you use SSG, it will run only at build time.
This way when you use client side routing, you will only receive the `_data.json` generated at build time and use that to populate the page component with required data (kinda like Next.js does it).